# Programs doesn't conntect to the internet without Fiddler

Tags: windows-7, proxy, internet-connection, fiddler

There was a time when I was using Fiddler very often for development puproses. At some point I stopped and realized that some programs doesn't conntect to the internet when fiddler is off. At the time it was only Visual Studio, I couldn't look for NuGet packages, my Resharper subscription was not able to verify itself.
Few months later I've installed Discord and there is also the problem. when I start Discord it checks for updates, and when there is no Fiddler open, it will fail to communicate.
I have uninstalled Fiddler thinking that this will help, but it didn't.
Is there some sort of setting I have changed and don't remember or what could be possibly wrong with my OS that this is happening?
I am running Windows 7 SP 1 x64.

Comment: Fix your proxy.

Comment: @DavidPostill Where exactly?

Comment: @DavidPostill, for what you have mentioned - it wasn't checked, also internet connection works fine for almost all programs, just for few doesn't.

Comment: So you need to check the settings for the individual programs that don't work. There is probably a proxy (that no longer exists) somewhere in their configurations. The simplest option may be to just reinstall them.

Comment: I have uninstalled Discord and downloaded installer. The installer is not even able to connect to the internet.